# Vectorization in PCA

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, pca

i am doing  Principal Component Analysis,and want help  to know if can represent 
**summation from i to m (X(i)*X(i)^T)** in terms of data matrix..direct multiplication of two matrices.

Can this be done..or need i use a for loop and do it.

Currently i have tried

```
     sum=zeros(n,n);
     for i=1:m
     sum=sum+ X(i,:)*(X(i,:)^T);
     end
```

My goal is to find the principal eigen values of the resulting matrix.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an attempt to answer your question, but it's not good to use `sum` as a variable name! It is already a [builtin function](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) in Matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say the shape of the data matrix `X` is (Dim, Num), you can just compute sum of all sample correlations with:

```
S = X*X'
```

For implementing PCA, also don't forget to divide the matrix by the amount of samples.

```
Sigma = (1/N)X*X'
```

If your data has zero mean, this is also the covariance matrix.